# Can't install pygame on Mac using pip3 install pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame using pip3 install pygame but this error appears:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5p/25vgdgh93qvg09z18wyy0mg00000gn/T/pip-install-_f8kcuyb/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/5p/25vgdgh93qvg09z18wyy0mg00000gn/T/pip-install-_f8kcuyb/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/5p/25vgdgh93qvg09z18wyy0mg00000gn/T/pip-record-gd9_k1m6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/5p/25vgdgh93qvg09z18wyy0mg00000gn/T/pip-install-_f8kcuyb/pygame/

Send help =(

Answer (score 1):

1. Before installing Pygame, there are many dependencies that will need
   to be installed. Begin by installing the XCode developer tools,
   which can be done through the app store.
2. Next you will need to install the latest version of XQuartz. You can
   start the installation by visiting the site ([here](https://www.xquartz.org/)).
3. Open a Terminal window. This can be done by pressing command+Space
   (⌘+Space) and typing Terminal in the search bar and pressing Enter.
   [image]
4. You now need to install Homebrew. You can do this by typing the
   following command in the Terminal and pressing Enter:

   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
5. After the installation is finished, you will need to type the
   following commands in the Terminal, pressing Enter after each one

   echo export PATH='usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile

   brew update

   brew doctor
6. You can now install Python 3 using Homebrew. To do this, type the
   following command in the Terminal and press Enter:

   brew install python3
7. Now you need to install several dependencies for Pygame. Type the
   following commands in the Terminal, pressing Enter after each one:

   brew install mercurial

   brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
   brew tap homebrew/headonly

   brew install smpeg
8. You are ready to install Pygame. Type the following command in the
   Terminal and press Enter. Note that you will probably have to enter
   your password in the Terminal in order for the command to run:

   sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
9. To verify the installation, you will have to launch the correct
   version of IDLE. You can find this by opening Finder, clicking on Go
   in the top left of the screen, then clicking on the Go to Folder…
   option.
10. In the search bar, enter /usr/local/Cellar/python and click Go.
     Navigate to the folder where Python 3 is located. It will probably
     be named in this format: 3.x.x.
11. Launch the IDLE 3 app within the folder. When launched, it should 
     be using Python 3.x.x. In the IDLE interpreter, type the following 
     command and press Enter:

    ```
    import pygame
    ```

    If the command completed without throwing any errors, you have
     successfully installed Pygame and found the correct version of IDLE
     to use for Pygame programming.
12. To make finding this version of IDLE easier, you can create a
     Desktop shortcut for IDLE 3. If you want to do this, press and hold
     the control key and click on IDLE 3. It will open a Menu where you
     can select Make Alias and create another IDLE 3 icon. You can name
     this icon whatever you like, but make sure to drag it to your
     Desktop when you are done.